# existence of such continuous function satisfies the following system of equations

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

A friend of mine asked me this question for such function. My first instinct is that such a function doesn't exist which needs to be proven by contradiction and use MVT. But I kinda stuck with how to use A and B in given condition.

Let $A > 0$ and $B ≠ 0$. Show that there does not exist a continuous function $f : [0,1] → R $ that
satisfies the following equations:
$$
f''(x)=A*{f(x)}   \quad
(0<x<1)
$$
$$
f(1)=f(0)=B
$$

$$
\lim_{x→1} f'(x) = \lim_{x→0} f'(x)
$$

Any suggestion or solution would be greatly appreciated

update:

initial thought (there's flaw)

First condition shows the existence of second differentiability. By MVT, there exists at least one point $c$ in $(0,1)$ such that $f′(c) = f(1) - f(0)=0$,

I was just told that no such formula exists

I tried to follow the posted comment and answer, but they lead nowhere. I got some really strange equations that's Obviously not the intention of the questioner。

Comment: The solutions of the first of your three equations are known explicitly.

Comment: @PhoemueX f = c1 *e^(Ax) /A +c2 ? Though I can't see how to use it

Comment: Solutions to the first equation are rather $f(x) = (ax+b)e^{\sqrt A x}$. Then you are to find (or to show that you cannot find) $a$ and $b$ such that the other two conditions are satisfied.

Comment: note that the first condition is only valid when 0<x<1, it does not apply to the second equation

Comment: You require the function to be continuous so it does not matter. You can extend the function by continuity to the endpoints.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the hint another step, using different letters for clarity,   we have $$f(x) = (cx+d)e^{\sqrt A x}$$
using the second,  $$f(0)=d=B$$
thus $$f(1)=(c+B)e^{\sqrt A}=B$$
a bit of algebra gets you to
$$c=\frac {B-Be^{\sqrt A}}{e^\sqrt A}=B(e^{-\sqrt A}-1)$$
so $$f(x)=B((e^{-\sqrt A}-1)x+1)e^{\sqrt Ax}$$

From here,  take your derivatives and your limits and see what happens.

Comment: since the first equation is only valid when 0<x<1, can we use its solution to the second equation?

Comment: The function is only defined on $[0,,1]$ and is continuous,  so the condition on $0<x<1$ requires the extension to the endpoints.

Comment: follow your step, for limx→1f′(x)=limx→0f′(x), we have B(√A-e^(√A)) = B(e^(-√A)+√A-1) =>e^(-√A)+e^(√A) = 1 = 2cosh√A ...?

Comment: I think that $f(x) = (cx+d)e^{\sqrt A x}$ is not correct. From the first equation we get $f(x) = ce^{\sqrt A x}+de^{-\sqrt A x}.$

Comment: @Fred Yeah, I think you're right. I was half awake when I did this and I took the solution presented uncritically from the comments.  I'll fix this in in a bit